# Does not belong to the group

Tags: number-sequence

One of these numbers does not belong to the group

3, 11, 17, 23, 29, 73, 77

With my logic I came up with two solutions

Comment: Please see [Number Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) to do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Comment: This is too broad as seen by the two answers given(unless they are the ones you had got).

Answer (score 4):

> 11

Because

> It is the only number you can spell without the letter "t"

Comment: another valid solution, closing as too broad

Comment: The other solution is all have only "e" as a vowel except one

Answer (score 2):

> 77 - with 12 now removed, it's the only non-prime remaining